# Why isnt my routing via Routing & Direct access working?

Tags: windows-10, router, routing, gateway

I tried to configure routing in Routing & Direct access in VMWare. It is not working, I want to ask why. The error is always : Destination host unreachable / Request timed out (for all paths when the routing is supposed to make it work)

This is the model I have : (everything have mask /24)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoPZx.png]

configuration on the servers :

[image]

[image: S2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QtCp.png]

[image: S3 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/75teJ.png]

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: What are the third columns? It seems that you are confused about direct route and indirect route.

Comment: They have the same destination but goes throught a different gateway, tried that since 2 columns didnt work. This havent changed it.

Comment: Ah never mind. I misinterpreted your post. Apparently the routes listed above are supposed to be indirect routes for remote networks.

Comment: Does e.g. PC1 use 194.251.25.2 as its default gateway (and LAN4 as its default interface, if there are more than one)?

Comment: Do you mean PC2 ? Default gateways are set for the PCs, do I need to set them for servers also ? PC2 is just in LAN4 so default interface shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: Ah yes I meant PC2. My point is, the LAN hosts / PCs need to have proper return route(s), assuming no NAT is involved in the scenario.

Comment: Maybe it will start working if I set gateway for every single network ? What do you think ?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary though, at least not on the PCs as per the diagram (although I have no idea what the `ping, tracert` lines between them mean).

Comment: It just means ping and tracert should work from PC1 to PC2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem. Some of the routes weren't configured correctly and there was a mistake with default gateway on PC2.